# ksoap2 - SoapObject 'source not found'

Tags: web-services, blackberry, ksoap2

I have a code for the BlackBerry App where the "login" button is clicked to fetch xml data. However nothing turns up when I try to show the response returned from the webservice that accepts username and password. My MDS is selected and the browser shows the internet to be working. However I do not see any **disable registration** option in the debugger configuration window as some posts suggest. My problem is how to get the server response. In the simulator debug console, no `System.println` msgs are showing up. Debugging line by line, when it comes to the code

```
SoapObject rpc = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
```

debugger produces the error "Source not found". My focus has actually shifted from getting the server response to actually fixing the path to ksoap2 as it appears not to be found. Any tips on this? Thanks

Comment: When you get to that line of code (`new SoapObject()`), are you telling the debugger to **step into**, or **step over** the line?  Are you building your project with a **.jar** file that contains the `ksoap` source code, or do you have all the individual **.java** source files from the `ksoap` library copied into your project, under the source folder you're using for your own java source code?

Comment: have you included the ksoap2 jar in your project ?

Comment: Hi. In the debugger I have tried both, earlier I was doing "Step out" and later with "Step into". Both result in the same. I have copied ksoap2-j2me-core-prev-2.1.2.jar into my project by adding it to the build path: Project right click->Properties->Java Build Path. Under the source folder of the project I have only one .java source code file which I have written down.

Comment: This is what I am getting right now while debugging "Step Over": String org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject.toString()


Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found

Comment: At the end of my debugging I got the error "No Wifi Connection found". My Simulator is working with "Simulated network" written on the home screen and my connection string to the web service "httpt = new HttpTransport(URL+ ";deviceside=true;ConnectionUID=S TCP-WiFi". How do I change it to use the "Simulated network". I used simulator browser and internet is working. Sorry about writing in chunks of messages.

Comment: Guys, I finally managed to get it working :) Problem was the connection string. I was not assigning the correct network.